# RegEx for password validation, only specific characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a Regular Expression for password validation. Here are the requirements.

1. Minimum length 8.
2. At least 1 upper case.
3. At least 1 lower case.
4. At least 1 number.
5. 0 or more of these characters !@#$%^&*?_~()- allowed.
6. a-z allowed.
7. A-Z allowed.
8. 0-9 allowed.

Here is the expression i have so far:

`^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*?_~()-]*).*$`

This expression works mostly, except i need it to only allow bullets 5-9. Right now it will allow characters that are not specified, for example `+=`.

How can i modify this expression to only allow bullets 5-9 and no other characters?

Comment: Why are you limiting the characters in passwords? More importantly why are other characters a problem for your password storage?

Comment: Why not use separate checks for these?

Comment: Not certain what you mean by _"allow 5-9 and no other characters"_?

Comment: @PeeHaa The backend is already designed that way.

Comment: @melpomene I am a noob when it comes to regex. I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: Fix the backend, because it sounds utterly broken.

Comment: @PeeHaa There are reasons to limit certain characters. For instance, if you were to use `pi` as one of your characters in the password, how are you going to type that on a mobile phone? It is not "utterly broken", just not how you would design it. And some times you do not have the option to change the backend.

Comment: @guest271314 They are the bullet points.

Comment: " if you were to use pi as one of your characters in the password, how are you going to type that on a mobile phone" that is up to the user. Don't weaken security for no reason. And yes that thing is utterly broken.

Comment: @PeeHaa Good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need lookahead-checks for the first and for the fifth to eigth condition - you can check this all in the final match, like

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[\w!@#$%^&*?~()-]{8,}$
```

Using your lookahead checks for conditions 2-4. For the actual match we need at least 8 characters of your allowed characters. I have used `\w` intead of `a-zA-Z0-9_` to keep things a bit shorter.

You can see it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/eF6qN1/1).

Site note: Restricting characters in passwords is usually seen as a bad idea. Also [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/936/) has something to say about passwords.

Answer (score 1):

You can break the `RegExp` into discrete portions, add or remove required portion, use `Array.prototype.every()`, include `&& !/[+=]/.test(str)` within function, and `.length` property of input string

```js
var matches = [/[A-Z]/, /[a-z]/, /\d/, /[!@#$%^&*?_~()-]/];
var str = "Ab0!#?~_";
var pw = matches.every(function(re) {
  return re.test(str) && !/[+=]/.test(str)
}) && str.length === 8;
console.log(pw);
```